# In a Silverlight CustomControl how can you layout elements of that control according to a Grid that contains the Control?

Tags: silverlight, layout, silverlight-4.0, custom-controls

Assume a custom control in Silverlight that has three TextBlock elements named Left, Middle and Right. I want to place the control inside of a grid that has three columns, and I would like the position of those elements to be the same as if I had defined them inline using Grid.Column="x" syntax, with the Grid.Row attached property being set on the custom control itself.

Or if I am completely off-base, what is the best way to achieve a similar result.

Comment: You have to define first why you think that you have a requirement for a custom control at all?

Comment: I should have gone with concrete examples from the start. Here are two:
1. Third parties provide controls to us that we then load via MEF and place within a Gird layout and we want the elements that they define to be in columns that match the host.
2. A [Label - TextBox - DescriptionViewer] control that binds to an Entity Property. We will write hundreds of these and want them to be consistent across the board. Also the XAML syntax with this approach is, to me, much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its likely that you are way "off-base".  The purpose of a custom control is to present data in a unique way.  If you want to hand out the the layout to an external grid then I would suggest that you don't have call for a custom control.

It seems more likely that you would want a class that has three properties to which you are simply binding three TextBlocks.  Without further particulars its hard to give better advice.

To answer your actual question, you can't.  You would need to add individual elements directly to the Children collection of the Grid in order for the grid to take charge of their layout.  This means that these elements cannot appear as child visual elements inside your custom control.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that you are off-base :) but you must have a good reason for seeking that solution.

In your CustomControl you override OnApplyTemplate. In this method you can find the three TextBlocks and set the Grid.Column value using SetValue.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    /// Find TextBlock named "Left"
    var left = GetTemplateChild("Left") as TextBlock;
    left.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

    ...
}
```

Comment: This just isn't going to work.  The TextBlock is not a member of the Grid Children collection so isn't going to be laid out by the Grid.

Comment: I am new to SO -- I tried to give acceptance to both this and above. Technically, I think this is impossible with XAML, although I think it is a flaw as this could be powerful if used correctly. The best way to achieve this effect is probably something like this answer \, but I think it would be a little more involved -- passing in the layout element that you want to take cues from and then responding to that elements layout events. Thanks for the responses.